# Append items into Firebase Firestore array

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Started learning Firebase and am using Firestore.

I have a field which is an array of strings but I don't understand how it works and how to append items to it from Android (Java).

Can anyone show me an example of pushing data to an array in Firebase? I have tried to search on google but all I find is high level stuff and not for beginners.

For context the document is users and the field in question is purchaseHistory

Also someone asked me to add a screenshot of the db and a code example, I don't have a code example because I haven't tried anything yet (I was going off of the documentation).

[Here is the database tho](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1POw.png)

Comment: Can you share any code that you've tried so far? You can use `ArrayUnion` to do so as mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array)

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and indicate the exact array you want to update. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @Dharmaraj But it says that ArrayUnion only adds items if they don't already exist, I need to add items even if they already exist in the array. Escpecially when it comes to purchase history in the screenshot

Comment: @AlexMamo Did that

Comment: I cannot see any array type field. Can you please be more clear?